# Rank of a matrix based on invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

How does $\operatorname{rank} [AB]$ depend on $\operatorname{rank}[A]$ & $\operatorname{rank}[B]$ when

> $A$ is invertible;
>   $A$ & $B$ both are invertible;
>   $A$ & $B$ both are non-invertible

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then the rank of $AB$ is the same as that of $B$. If both are invertible, then all $A,B,AB$ have full rank. Otherwise you can say that $rank[AB]\leq \min(rank[A],rank[B])$.

Answer (score 1):

It always holds that
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\rank(AB)\le\min\{\rank(A),\rank(B)\}\tag{*}
$$
but nothing more can be said in general.

If $A$ is invertible, then we can say
$$
\rank(B)=\rank(A^{-1}(AB))\le\rank(AB)\le\rank(B)
$$
because of (*), so $\rank(AB)=\rank(B)$.

If $A$ and $B$ are invertible $n\times n$ matrices, then they both have rank $n$.